# Gradle script to bootRun submodules

Tags: gradle

I'm just wondering.. Is it possible to create gradle task which can run my services(bootRun) in some sequence?
I have a submodule project and I wanna run all of my services, but first serviceA, second serviceB etd. but I doing this manually is tiring :D

Comment: What do you mean by "first serviceA, second serviceB". Do you want to start serviceA first and then start serviceB right after, or do you want to wait for serviceA to finish and then start serviceB?